# PhantomJS PDF file to Base64

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I'm working with PhantomJS and doing PDF Files from rendering my own website, right now works perfectly (the file is creating, everything seems just ok at localhost).

All this comes from a Post all the way from my actual server (NoseJS), i'm trying to send in response the .pdf PhantomJS made, I tried sending binary, base64 and all kind of ways I found in the web... Right now i'm converting the file to base64 in phantom and sending it to Node, Node creates the file and the file comes in blank and bigger in size (Phantom file: 15Mb, Node file: 29Mb)

My question is, does anyone know an easy way through?

My code right now:

PhantomJS:

```
function utf8_to_b64(str) {
  return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}

var server = require('webserver').create();
var fs = require('fs');

var port = require('system').env.PORT || 8080; // default back to 8080
server.listen(port, function(request, response) {

  if (request.method === 'POST') {
    var page = new WebPage();
    var objeto = request.post;

    page.paperSize = {
      format: 'A4',
      orientation: 'portrait',
      margin: '1cm'
    };

    page.open("http://google.com", function(status) {
      if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
      } else {

        //page.render(app + '.pdf', {
        page.render('prueba.pdf', {
          format: 'pdf',
          quality: '100'
        });

        var archivo = fs.open('prueba.pdf', 'r');
        archivo = archivo.read();
        archivo = utf8_to_b64(archivo);
        console.log('done');
        //fs.remove('prueba.pdf');

        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.headers = {
          'Content-type': 'text/plain'
        };
        response.write(archivo);
        response.close();
        page.close();

        //phantom.exit();

      }

    });
  }
});
```

NodeJS:

```
request
  .post('http://localhost:8080/')
    .send({
      app: req.body.app,
      url: 'google.com'
    })
    .end(function(err, respond) {
      console.log('post a phantom');
      console.log('error: ', err);
      fs.writeFile('prueba.pdf', respond.text, 'base64', function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('It\'s saved!');
      });
      res.json(resJSON.ok());
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say the file "comes in blank", is it full of NULL characters, or does it look empty if a PDF reader?  If you view the raw file in a text editor, does it resemble a normal PDF file?

Comment: I wonder if this question is not really about PhantomJS, but rather about transferring a binary file to NodeJS?  Have you tried `response.headers = { 'Content-type': 'application/pdf' };`?

Comment: It came in blank. I made a lot of research about this topic, at the end I conclude it wasn't the best way, I mean, phantomJS and NodeJS are not meant to be together (romantic haha), there are other rendering packages in npm or go the long way and pay an outsource service that can render websites, pdfcrowd was my choice and worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you!